# How do I create a column in Users list and display user data from custom registration field

Tags: custom-field, user-meta

Our registration form has a custom field for Hospital Name. In SQL `wp_usermeta` the meta_key is `user_registration_hospital`. I have tested a number of snippets in the `functions.php` file to add a "Hospital" column to the Users admin table, all of which create the Hospital column in the Users list. This is one of the snippets that adds the Hospital column:

```
function add_user_columns($column) {
   $column['hospital'] = 'Hospital';
   return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_user_columns' );
```

What code do I need to add to the functions.php file to have the Hospital data from *wp_usermeta* populate the Hospital column?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to add new column and show data properly.

```
function add_user_columns_hospital( $column ) {
    $column['hospital'] = 'Hospital';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_user_columns_hospital' );

function modify_user_table_row_hospital( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'hospital' :
            return get_the_author_meta( 'user_registration_hospital', $user_id );
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```